# Why do I get React.Children only expected error?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to use a bootstrap-react component `<Collapse>` that will be a child of a `<Cart>` component::

```
<div>
    <Cart></Cart>
</div>
```

This is the part of the render of Cart component:

```
<Collapse>
        <div className="row">
            <hr/>
            <div className="col-md-2"></div>
            <div className="col-md-2"></div>
            <div className="col-md-1"></div>
            <div className="col-md-2">Upfront</div>
            <div className="col-md-1"></div>
            <div className="col-md-2">Monthly</div>
            <div className="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
</Collapse>
```

This is the error I get:

```
Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
```

Why do I get React.Children only expected error?

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: there you go this is the full error

Comment: I'm almost certain from your post that the error is not in the code you posted, could expands your code snippets to give a better overview

Comment: you are right I stuffed up , it works now

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `< Collapse />` from the `Cart` component.

```
<Collapse in={test}>
  <Cart></Cart>
</Collapse>
```

**cart**

```
<div className="row">
     <div className="col-md-2"></div>
     <div className="col-md-2">TOTAL</div>
     <div className="col-md-2">Upfront</div>
     <div className="col-md-2">Monthly</div>
     <div className="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No because I want to nest the Collapse if possible

Comment: It is possible but you will expected outputs.

Comment: it is all fixed